# How can I load a unique database ID onto a MarkupCore extension markup?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the MarkupsCore extension to build a cloud-based annotation system. I am able to successfully store markups in the database individually, and load them back as one whole SVG string. However, I am confused on being able to delete them. Ordinarily, I would attach a database ID to the markup, and delete it by that. But, I do not know how I would do that in this case. Are there any unique attributes that I could store that are part of the markups to use to identify them to delete them with?

Also, is there a particular reason that the MarkupsCore extension doesn't have an event that is fired when a markup is created? I was able to resolve this problem myself, but I am just curious.

Comment: How exactly do you extract the data for storage? Using the `generateData()` method of the extension?

Comment: Nope. I recreate the svg using a template and I fill in the metadata appropriately.

Comment: The thing about generate data that is it means that if you are developing a cloud-based markup solution, you always have to trust that the clients are in sync, or you are going to end up overwriting markups. Saving them individually solves this, since you don't get any overwriting, but it makes everything else harder, because I don't think the tool was imagined to be used this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You're right - the standard way of storing and loading the markup data (using `generateData()` and `loadMarkups()`) does not consider multi-user workflows. Storing the markup elements separately makes multi-user workflows possible, but it means that you cannot use the `loadMarkups()` function, since it sanitizes the markup and removes all unknown metadata. I'll post an alternative approach as a proposed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bypass the standard storage mechanism (using the `generateData()` and `loadMarkups()` methods on the MarkupCore extension), you could potentially store the data separately, and re-create the markup procedurally using the following approach:

```
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore').then((extension) => {
    const CoreNS = Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core;
    extension.clear();
    extension.enterEditMode();
    let rect = new CoreNS.MarkupRectangle(123 /* your custom ID */, extension);
    extension.addMarkup(rect);
    rect.setSize({ x: 10, y: 10 }, 100 /* width */, 100 /* height */);
    extension.leaveEditMode();
    console.log('markup data', extension.generateData());
});
```

Comment: av.Extensions.Markups.Core doesn't seem to exist. I have tried on V6 and V2.

Comment: This snippet of code assumes that the extension has already been loaded. Let me update the code to ensure that.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I didn't get a chance to try it yet. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you were able to use this approach in your scenario. Oh and one more thing: keep in mind that when the user actually draws the markup, the extension will assign each element a numerical ID based on its own internal counter, so you'll want to make sure that there's no collisions with your custom-defined IDs.

Comment: So, when I add a text markup using the workflow from before, and use the setText function to set the text, it works, but there is an issue. The markup doesn't show up until I click somewhere on the viewer OR I hover over it, then it appears. Any suggestions?

Comment: For all wondering, in order to get the text markup working. You have to call the updateStyle(true) function on the markup as you are creating it. Otherwise it will be invisible.